# .NET Framework 3.5 and HttpResponseMessage not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a .Net framework 3.5 project which currently need REST service implementation. I am using Visual Studio 2008 for development. I am currently returning the class object as JSON. Below is the code sample,

IRestService.cs

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate = "get_product/?producer_id={producerID}")]
Products getProducts(int producerID);
```

RestService.svc.cs

```
public Products getProducts(int producerID)
{
    var allProduct = GetAllProduct(producerID);
    var serializedProduct = new Products();

    foreach (var product in allProduct)
    {
        serializedProduct.products.Add(product.productName);
    }
    return serializedProduct;
}
```

The method above is returning the Product details for the Id provided. But if no product exists for the Id provided, it is return the null JSON value.

In .Net 4.0 we can use HttpResponseMessage as return type to fix this. I also use HttpResponseMessage as return type, but i am getting the following error `"The type or namespace name 'HttpResponseMessage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"`.

Can any one tell me what is the equivalent of HttpResponseMessage in .Net 3.5 (VS2008).

Please help me.

Comment: In is only available in Net 4.5 or later (Windows 8 and above).  Try ToString().  See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse_methods(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @jdweng may i know the alternative usage.

Comment: Either ToString, innerHtml, innerText, outerHtml, outerText.

Comment: @jdweng That means i should create the binding with return type string/innerText.Is it right.